# How do I embed hyperlinks from one excel file into text from another excel file with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, hyperlink, embed

Good Evening everyone,

I have a problem that I am having some issues with and I really need some help. I took two csv files and compared them and converted them to an xls.  Now the part I am confused about is how will I be able to take the hyperlinks from Column 1, Row 1 in one excel document and embed them into the text in the other document Column 1, Row2.

is there an easy way to do this?  I found the follow link which left me a little confused : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/123d673a-f9a7-4ae6-ae9c-d4ae8ef65015/powershell-excel-how-do-i-create-a-hyperlink-to-a-cell-in-another-sheet-of-the-document?forum=ITCG

I appreciate any guidance and help you can offer.

```
#Define the file path and sheet name
$FilePath= `enter 
code"C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test3.csv"
$FilePath2="C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test3.xls"
$FilePath3="C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test4.xls"
$SheetName="Test3"
$SheetName2="HyperLinks"

#Compare two CSV files to look for matches
$CSV1 = import-csv -path 
C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test1.csv
$CSV2 = import-csv -path 
C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test2.csv
Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -property ShoppingList -IncludeEqual | where-
object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} 

# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Enable the 'visible' property so the document will open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $False

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
# Load the WorkSheet "Test3" 
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)

# Delete data from column
[void]$WorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,2).EntireColumn.Delete()

#Auto fit everything so it looks better
$usedRange = $WorkSheet.UsedRange   
$usedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#Save and convert to XLS
$Workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\HomeWork2\Test3.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True

#Load 
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

$excel.Visible = $True

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

$workbook.Worksheets.Item($FilePath2).Hyperlinks.Add( `
$workbook.Worksheets.Item($FilePath2).Cells.Item(1,2) , `
"" , $FilePath3, "https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/673034-powers
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; however, the data in in another file not another sheet within the same file.  Therefore this method requires some tweaking, which I attempted to do based on the link I posted.  
                                                                                                  
Additionally, we do not want to use the other file on our site once the data has been extrapolated.             Do I have to figure out how to use arrays to do this, or is there an easier way to extrapolate and embed the links into one file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

$excel.Visible = $True

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Hyperlinks.Add($workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Cells.Item(1,1) ,"" , "Sheet2!C4", "", "Link to sheet2")
```

Reference : [Hyperlinks.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211819(office.12).aspx)

Hope it helps